# Should I avoid using classes in Spring util package?

Tags: java, spring

There are many useful utility classes under the `org.springframework.util` package, however, many of them also has this on their document.

> Mainly for internal use within the framework

Is it safe to use these classes in application ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is fine to use them. Those classes provide `static` helper methods that shouldn't contain any mutable `static` state.

Answer (score 1):

If the classes and methods are public, it is safe. Read the documentation carefully to make sure that there will not be any side effects on the rest of the framework.